# python Mock post inside a method

Tags: python, unit-testing

How can I mock a post inside a method, so i can have unittests?

```
    def send_report(self, data):
        url = settings.WEBHOOK_PO
        payload = json.dumps(data)
        requests.post(url, data=payload)
        url = settings.WEBHOOK_LQA
       response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
       return response.status_code
```

Is there a way to cover this method for unit test with not actually posting?

Comment: One option: https://github.com/getsentry/responses

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mock` library to replace `requests.post` with something else:

```
with mock.patch('requests.post') as mock_post:
    foo.send_report(data)
```

(`mock` is a [third-party package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock), but was added to the standard library, as part of the `unittest` package`, in Python 3.3.)

`mock_post` can be configured to provide the desired behavior during the test; consult the `mock` documentation for details.

---

Another option is to modify your method to take the `post` function as an argument, rather than hard-coding the function (this is an example of *dependency injection*):

```
def send_report(self, data, poster=requests.post):
    url = settings.WEBHOOK_PO
    payload = json.dumps(data)
    poster(url, data=payload)
    url = settings.WEBHOOK_LQA
    response = poster(url, data=payload)
    return response.status_code
```

When you want to test the function, you simply pass a different callable object as the optional second argument.

Note that you can supply separate functions for the two types of posts, which might make it easier to test than with a mock:

```
from functools import partial

def send_report(self,
                data,
                post_po=partial(requests.post, settings.WEBHOOK_PO),
                post_lqa=partial(requests.post, settings.WEBHOOK_LQA)):
    payload = json.dumps(data)
    post_po(data=payload)
    response = post_lqa(data=payload)
    return response.status_code
```

Comment: `mock` works with 2.6 or later; it was just not until 3.3 that it became part of the standard library.